# Netsuite code to return 503 Status when site is taken offline

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, http-status-code-503, scriptlet

How can I write code to return 503 status when the site is offline and how can I check if the site is offline while writing the code. We are using Netsuite as cloud database for the site. Hints about the event to throw 503 status error especially in netsuite context are much appreciated.

Thank You.

Comment: What is your main site written in?

Comment: Backbone JS with handlebars, Underscore, Jquery, Javascript